# Как переопределить индексацию для работы с векторами и матрицами?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Собственно, вся суть вопроса в описании.
Пишу библиотеку для работы с [векторами](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_(%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)) и [матрицами](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_(%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)). Для этого пришлось переопределять сложение, умножение и пр. Возник вопрос: Как можно переопределить индексацию для этих объектов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Операции индексации реализуются с помощью [`__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, `__delitem__` специальных методов](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types). Документация operator модуля содержит исчерпывающую [таблицу отображения операторов на функции](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions).

`collections.abc` документация показывает какие методы минимально следует реализовать, чтобы выполнить обязательства [Sequence/MutableSequence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) (чтобы объект себя вёл похоже на встроенные строки/списки).

Для типа полезного для вычислений, можно посмотреть какие свойства/методы реализованы в [`numpy.ndarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html).